# Bot Framework -500 Internal Server Error

Tags: c#-4.0, bots

I am new to `bot` framework by `Microsoft`. I made a simple `bot` and registered it in `bot connector`. When I now want to test my `bot` on the `dev.framework.com` site I get this message `Endpoint authorization succeeded`, but always getting `500 internal server error`, here I attached screen.
[image]

Comment: This happens locally (on my pc) as well, and no breakpoints are hit. I am thinking the emulator is not connecting correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the "**Using the Emulator with Ngrok to interact with your bot in the cloud**" section in https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/tools/bot-framework-emulator/. We were working on the Bot Framework and this document has helped us resolve the same Internal Server Error - 500.

Also after publishing your bot to the **Azure Cloud Service**, you should point the **Emulator Url** to the "**ngrok url**" which you'll obtain after following the procedure specified in the above documentation rather than your localhost:9000.

This should help resolve your issue.

Thanks

SaiSandeep | Team Imaginea

http://www.imaginea.com/practices/microsoft/